# How to efficiently use a binary file in a pyspark UDF?

Tags: python, apache-spark, maxmind

This is not a duplicate of [Usage of custom Python object in Pyspark UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692370/usage-of-custom-python-object-in-pyspark-udf) because whereas that troubleshoots the usage of an outside file this is a request for best practices.

To begin, I'm sure this would be more efficient in Scala, but adding a new language to my ecosystem isn't feasible.

My problem is I have a Hive database containing IP addresses, and I would like to map each of them to its parent Autonomous System Number (ASN).

MaxMind offers [several downloadable databases](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/) containing various IP metadata, including Geolocation, ASNs, etc., and additionally several [reference implementations](http://maxmind.github.io/MaxMind-DB/#reference-implementations) of code to read these databases. The databases themselves are efficiently-packed binary trees in the [MaxMind DB Format](http://maxmind.github.io/MaxMind-DB/) and are difficult to unroll into something suitable for a database join.

My plan to do this mapping is to create a PySpark UDF around their Python database reader, like so:

```
def mmdbv(x):

    import maxminddb

    reader = maxminddb.open_database(SparkFiles.get("GeoIP2-ISP.mmdb"))

    try:
        foo = reader.get(x)['autonomous_system_number']
    except:
        foo = None
    finally:
        reader.close()

    return foo


if __name__== "__main__":

    spark = (SparkSession
            .builder
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
            .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
            .getOrCreate())

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

    spark.sparkContext.addPyFile('maxminddb-1.3.0-py3.6.egg')
    spark.sparkContext.addFile('GeoIP2-ISP.mmdb')

    mf = F.udf(mmdbv, T.IntegerType())

    main()


    spark.stop()
```

This is very inefficient, essentially elementwise creating a file handle, opening, reading and closing. Is there a better way?

Comment: Is unpacking the binary tree into a flat file containing all its paths feasible? Spark works with such data well.

Comment: Not really, I tried that first. The DB is small because it's a tree, but to unroll it I'd need to have a row for every possible IPv4 and IPv6 address, which would be titanic even for IPv4 alone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46694426/8371915

Comment: Or just use `RDD.mapPartitions`.

Comment: This post has very little in common with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692370/usage-of-custom-python-object-in-pyspark-udf

Comment: @user8371915 what do you mean mapPartitions? Used how?

Comment: `df.rdd.mapPartitions(your_function)` where `your_function` opens the file, and then iterates over all elements in the partition (see [Design Patterns for using foreachRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd)) And questions have exactly the same problem - how to initialize object once for interpreter. Serialization is a secondary thing. Please read linked answer carefully - it does solve your problem.

Comment: I see what makes you suggest that they're similar (to the extent that we assume mapPartitions and running once per executor is ideal), although I'm not positive this is a duplicate. In any case, I reimplemented my approach with a function run via mapPartitions containing a closure to do the lookup, but I find that in fact mapPartitions is an order of magnitude slower across my tests (2min15sec vs 13sec, on average). Identical partitioning, fixed executor size, etc.