# Stateful udfs in spark sql, or how to obtain mapPartitions performance benefit in spark sql?

Tags: apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, user-defined-functions

Using map over map partitions can give significant performance boost in cases where the transformation incurs creating or loading an expensive resource (e.g - authenticate to an external service or create a db connection).

*mapPartition* allows us to initialise the expensive resource once per partition verses once per row as happens with the standard *map*.

But if I am using dataframes, the way I apply custom transformations is by specifying user defined functions that operate on a row by row basis- so I lose the ability I had with mapPartitions to perform heavy lifting once per chunk.

**Is there a workaround for this in spark-sql/dataframe?**

**To be more specific**:

I need to perform feature extraction on a bunch of documents. I have a function that inputs a document and outputs a vector.

The computation itself involves initialising a connection to an external service. I don't want or need to initialise it per document. This has non trivial overhead at scale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you have three options:

- Convert `DataFrame` to `RDD` and apply `mapPartitions` directly. Since you use Python `udf` you already break certain optimizations and pay serde cost and using `RDD` won't make it worse on average.
- Lazily [initialize required resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46694426/6910411) (see also [How to run a function on all Spark workers before processing data in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37343437/6910411)).
- If data can be serialized with Arrow use vectorized `pandas_udf` (Spark 2.3 and later). Unfortunately you cannot use it directly with `VectorUDT`, so you'd have to expand vectors and collapse later, so the limiting factor here is the size of the vector. Also you have to be careful to keep size of partitions under control.

Note that using `UserDefinedFunctions` might require [promoting objects to non-deterministic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42367629/6910411) variants.

Comment: I feared that there is no straightforward way to do this. Lazy init and pandas udf sound interesting. I will check it out.

Comment: BTW, what about maintaining state in a singleton object - why didnt you mention this as well?

Comment: Mostly because I don't find using singleton objects to be a good practice in Python. Furthermore the problem is more related to scope than anything else.